# "unresolved merge conflict" when not merging in git

Tags: git

I have a text file in my repository that uses strings of '=' to underline headers:

```
Header Text
===========
```

and when I try to `git commit` it complains of an "unresolved merge conflict", since git uses a string of '=' characters when marking conflicts.

How can I make git allow me to commit?

Comment: This didn't sound right to me so I create a new git repo, created a file with those contents, committed the file and pushed to github with no issues. My suspicion is that you do actually have a conflict somewhere. More details might make it easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I'm not starting with a new, empty repository.  I put the above text in a file, add it with `git add testGit`, and then commit with `git commit -m "Test"`, which gives me: `... You have some suspicious patch lines ...\n* unresolved merge conflict (line 2)\ntestGit:2:===========`. I'll check my commit hooks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is vague and the OP's answer doesn't provide any additional info. It is not of any use for the readers.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the pre-commit hook I'm using. I came up with 2 solutions:

a) Fix the logic in the pre-commit hook script.

b) Temporarily disable the pre-commit hook by renaming it "no-pre-commit", and then back to "pre-commit".

I didn't want to take the time to fix the script, so I went for (b).

Comment: Or simply `git commit --no-verify` (or `-n`), though this skips *both* `pre-commit` and `commit-msg` hooks.